# Is it possible to create a "before writing" Proxy for a Node.JS object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-proxy

Given an object like:

```
var box = { number: 20 }
```

I would like to tie a "before writing" [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) (or equivalent) to it. This proxy would act as a middleware and perform a type-check.

For example, after doing `box.number = "30"` It would verify that `typeof === "number"`. Since it is not, it would show an error.

Doing `box.number = 30` would not trigger the proxy.

---

What I've tried:

- [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy#Examples). Works only for undefined properties.
- [Watcher.JS](https://github.com/melanke/Watch.JS/) The value gets written and then the middleware is executed (because it is a watcher). The middleware should execute first.

What I know that can be done:

- I know that I can simply check the `typeof` of the variable beforehand. I am looking for a Proxy solution.
- Custom defined functions (getters & setters). I would like to experiment with proxies, all properties have dynamic names.

Comment: Use a CRUD method with get/set function, you can perform any checks before setting the actual value, and return true/false based on the result.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, and consdering your needs, **get/set** is a better approach, they are faster in execution time,  and  the code is easier to mantain.

### GETTERS/SETTERS SOLUTION

Are arround since the arrival of ES5...

> - A **getter** is a method that gets the value of a specific property.
> - A **setter** is a method that sets the value of a specific property.
>
> You can define getters and setters on any predefined core object or
>   user-defined object that supports the addition of new properties. The
>   syntax for defining getters and setters uses the object literal
>   syntax.

+info : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

```
var box = { 
    _number : 0,
    get number(){ return this._number },
    set number(value){ 
        /* your verifications here */
        if( typeof value !== 'number' ) throw new Error('Invalid input')
        /* if validates , asign value */
        this._number = value;
    }
}
// test...
box.number = "1234"; // FAIL
box.number = 1234;   // OK
box.number;          // output = 1234
```

---

### PROXY SOLUTION

Available since ES6. Probably not appropiate if performance is important for you. Use the *GET/SET proxy traps*, to obtain the same behavior as in the previous example.

```
// your original object...
var box = {};
// create a proxy linked to your original object
var boxProxy = new Proxy( box , {
    get( obj, prop, receiver ){ return obj[prop] },
    set( obj, prop, value){ 
        /* check if the property trying to be written is 'number' */
        if( prop === 'number' ){
             /* your verifications here */
            if( typeof value  !== 'number' ) throw new Error('Invalid input')
            /* if validates , asign value */
            this._number = value;
        }
    } 
 });
// test...
boxProxy.number = "1234"; // FAIL
boxProxy.number = 1234;   // OK
boxProxy.number;          // output = 1234
```

---

In both cases, if you require the propery `box._number` to be private and hidden you may implement it, using [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example, you have a verification code, and a default value

```
var box =Object.create({},{
number: {    
    get: function() { return this._number || 0; },
    set: function(value) {
      if(typeof value!='number') throw new Error('error')
      this._number=value
    }
}
})
```

If you want to hide the private `_number` you can wrap in a function

```
var box=(function() {
    var _number
    var box =Object.create({},{
    number: {    
        get: function() { return _number || 0; },
        set: function(value) {
          if(typeof value!='number') throw new Error('error')
          _number=value
        }
    }
    })
    return box
})()

box.number=3
```

## More info:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create